# Synchronizing (updating) published files

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

How can I update a published file and maintain the same URL?

After saving an update of a published file on my desktop, it will automatically "synchronise" with the corresponding files at UbuntuOne (and it does). Problem is that the "new file", actually the updated file with the same name, is no longer published. Pressing the publish button results is a new URL. I now have to mail new URL's and change embedded links, as old URL will result in a failure to find the updated file (or indeed any file).

I am not sure if it is a bug or a design flaw (maybe intentional?), but it seems strange to me.

Answer (score 2):

Right now it depends a lot on how you update the published file. For instance, copying over a published file with another file from outside the published folders works every time. Other scenarios I'd have to test to make sure, but I know some scenarios that would ideally work don't work yet. We will get round to fixing it so it "just works" in all the different scenarios, but regrettably not in time for the next release as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think it's a bit random at the time being. I don't know exactly on what it depends, but I had deferent results while updating a published file, more precisely replacing one by a new version. I used to do it some time ago and, as far as I know, it worked alright, but now I just did it again and had a bad surprise: the link still aims to the former version of the file, while my file browser and the online file browser have the new version. In my browser, I can right-click and "copy the url" (the file is meant to be published), which actually leads to the former version. And in the online browser, my file is said not to be published. And no track of the former version here (no ".u1conflict or so on). Thus, I can't even delete it.

Hence my conclusion: it seems still to be buggy, unfortunately :-s

I don't dare to publish the new file through the online browser, I fear it would give me another link and totally disable the former -broadcasted- one while hopefully I can find in a near future a way to overcome the problem...

Thanks to the developers anyway !

Comment: We cache published files for a small period of time; are you sure you weren't seeing that?

Answer (score 0):

A [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-client/+bug/652019?comments=all) is active on Launchpad. I'm very surprised to see that it is open since 2010.

Please note that the possibility to publish any file or folder, independently from its path is also available on Dropbox. (See http://www.dropbox.com/help/167)

I have done some tests of publishing and updating files using Dropbox, everything is fine with them. Any updated file keeps the same url and is published.

This confirms to me even more that we have now a competitive problem with Ubuntu One. Is there any chance that we get this solved before 2014?

Comment: After one year using the proprietary solution "dropbox" I am still happy with it, everything is fine. It is really a pitty cause I would really prefer using Ubuntu's tool.